# Is this python code iterative or recursive?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, iteration

I have written the following program in python:

```
def summ(a,b):
    return summation(a,a,a,b)

def summation(v,c,a,b):
    if (c == b):
        return v
    else:
        return summation(v+c+1,c+1,a,b)
```

### Research on types of algorithms

I am new to algorithms and programming in general and I wrote this code thinking it was an iterative algorithm but according to the following video:

[Algorithms lecture 2 -- Time complexity Analysis of iterative programs - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEnwM-iDb2g&list=PLEbnTDJUr_IeHYw_sfBOJ6gk5pie0yP-0&index=3&t=11s)

- *iterative* algorithms use loops such as 'while', 'for'
- *recursive* algorithms contain 'if .. then' statements

How can I figure out whether this is an *iterative* or a *recursive* algorithm?

Comment: Since the function `summation` calls itself again (under certain conditions) it is *recursive*. See Wikipedia on [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science).

Comment: @hc_dev thank you for the response, just a follow up question, so would the algorithm that I've written be considered as 'tail recursive', and is it entirely different from an iterative algorithm?

Comment: It’s tail recursive because the last action the function performs is the recursive call. Note, however, Python does not have tail recursion optimization, so this doesn’t buy you anything in Python.

Comment: @noobanomaly it's recursive. It's also tail recursive, not that it matters in Python. Some languages (not Python) can highly optimize recursive functions that are tail recursive. None of that has anything to do with iteration, other than the academic factoid that recursion and iteration are formally equivalent in expressive power: what you can do with one you can also do with the other. But that doesn't mean they are the same in their implementation.

Comment: The question already states criteria by which the answer is obvious. What exactly are you asking beyond that?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: `The question already states criteria` missing the most important one for *recursive*: a procedure calling itself, directly or indirectly.

Comment: @greybeard I agree that there are better criteria, but since it is asking about that specific example the criteria are already more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Iterative functions are the functions that execute a set of statements using some loops i.e "for loop", "while loop".

Recursive functions are the functions which call's itself repeatedly until base condition become false.
Recursive functions are the advanced one, and difficult to understand the flow of program.

In recursive we have a base condition on which all the flow is based.

```
def summation(v,c,a,b):
    if (c == b):
        return v
    else:
        return summation(v+c+1,c+1,a,b)
```

Above function is the recursive functions because it have a base function and calling itself in else block.

```
if(c == b):
   return v
```

Comment: You meant to say "Iterative" in your first sentence.

Comment: There's some grey area between the two. Consider `even = lambda x: if x == 0 then True else odd(x-1)` and `odd = lambda x: if x == 1 then True else even(x-1)`. Neither is iterative, and neither calls *itself* recursively. The pair together, though, are *mutally* recursive. Also, whether recursion is "advanced" or "difficult to understand" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Yep, i agree with your point. Recursive functions take times to understand especially when you are over viewing the code written by some other developers.                 Also you have use lambda expression in your example, according to my point of view lambda work like a function but without a name, so we can say that it acts like a recursive one.